# Cannot run "ruby script/server" rails/version (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am facing a problem starting the server for a ruby app built by somebody else. When I run the "ruby server/script" command, the following output is generated:

```
ruby script/server 
./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:7:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/version (LoadError)
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:7
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:45:in `require'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:45:in `load_initializer'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:109
    from script/server:2:in `require'
    from script/server:2
```

I have looked, and looked and no solution seems in sight.

Specs:

```
Ruby 1.8.7, 
Rails 2.2.2, 
gem -v 1.8.25
```

EDIT:
After doing that, I still get the same error:

```
[dralexmv@archbang rubygame]$ ruby script/server 
./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:7:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/version (LoadError)
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:7
```

Versions:

```
[dralexmv@archbang rubygame]$ gem -v 
1.4.2 
[dralexmv@archbang rubygame]$ rails -v 
Rails 2.2.2 
[dralexmv@archbang rubygame]$ ruby -v 
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [x86_64-linux]
```

EDIT: GEM LIST

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.2.2)
actionpack (2.2.2) 
activerecord (2.2.2) 
activeresource (2.2.2) 
activesupport (2.2.2) 
bundler (1.2.4) 
json (1.7.7) 
mysql (2.9.1) 
rails (2.2.2) 
rake (10.0.3) 
rdoc (4.0.0) 
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0) 
rubygems-update (1.4.2) 
rvm (1.11.3.6) 
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
```

EDIT: Test on a test app

```
[dralexmv@archbang test_a]$ ruby script/server
=> Booting WEBrick...
=> Rails 2.2.2 application started on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server; call with --help for options
[2013-03-10 12:06:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-03-10 12:06:35] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12) [x86_64-linux]
[2013-03-10 12:06:35] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11230 port=3000
```

Comment: `gem update --system 1.3.7` should fix the problem. Rails 2.x has some known issues running with gem -v 1.8.x

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your gem and try. Rails 2.X doesn't work with gem version greater than 1.5

```
sudo gem update --system 1.4.2
```

Comment: After doing that, I still get the same error:
[dralexmv@archbang rubygame]$ ruby script/server 
./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:7:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/version (LoadError)
 from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:7
Versions: 
[dralexmv@archbang rubygame]$ gem -v
1.4.2
[dralexmv@archbang rubygame]$ rails -v
Rails 2.2.2
[dralexmv@archbang rubygame]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: could you post `gem list` ??

Comment: gems look good. Try creating new app.. `rails test_app` and try starting server for newly created app.

Comment: I downloaded this project to make some modifications on it on my local machine. I cannot seem to be able to start the server even when I have done no changes. This project is known to work.

Gem list posted above

Comment: I think you have different version of rails app which you downloaded. Is there bundler in that app?? Is there `Gemfile` in that app??

Comment: Where would the Gemfile be located?

Comment: Gemfile will be immediate directory.

Comment: If Gemfile is not there can you go to `config/environment.rb` and check whats the rails version.

Comment: RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.2.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

Comment: This is there in `config/environment.rb` ?

Comment: `rake gems:install
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Technoweenie::AttachmentFu`

I am not possitive about what this means.

Comment: I am not getting the problem. You should ask who created or working that app. Only he can say what changes made to app and what's the enviroment to run that app. Because its not a generic problem. But Rials 2.X doesn't work with gem greater than 1.5. That is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have been quite helpful. I'll try to get in contact with the app creator.